# How to access AWS Batch environment variables from Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I am trying to access environment variables in the bash command but using `$VAR_NAME` does not work.

Here is how the definition looks like:

```
"container": {
   "image": "public.ecr.aws/amazonlinux/amazonlinux:latest",
   "command": [
     "echo",
     "$VAR_NAME"
   ],
   "environment": [
     {
       "name": "VAR_NAME",
       "value": "VALUE"
     }
  ]
}
```

What this does instead is echo the literal $VAR_NAME in the logs.

Not sure why AWS does not document this but was wondering how one actually uses the environment variables in the bash commands.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `["bash", "-c", "echo $VAR_NAME"]`